# Script for random movement (scatter)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, transform, script

I have found (and use) scripts for random opacity, random resize, random rotation etc. but I can't seem to find one which will do a "random displacement/move"

With the other above mentioned scripts, you simply select the paths, run the script and enter in a minimum value and a maximum value and the computer randomizes it for you. (Say min 20% opacity, max 80% opacity - they will all be between 20-80% opacity)

Is this script difficult to create?

Couldn't it just be enter in `min -X` and `min -Y` to `max X` and `max Y` movement? Then the computer would just choose a random value as it does in the other scripts.

Comment: Do you want it to work off a selection of items?

Comment: @Silly-V yes...

Comment: Well, you might as well be using the Transform dialog box and using the random checkbox as well as the move settings to create the variation range.

Comment: No its not hard to build takes about 3 minutes (but i have no computer to run illustrator on untill tomorrow). but this is built into the transform each command.

Comment: Using transform effect, I can only get it to move in one direction, not *both* (I can't do between -10 and 10, only 0 and 10)

Comment: do it two times once to left and once to right. You will also get a nicer distribution this way.

Comment: @joojaa aaaaand that's why I wanted a script so that I do it all at once, just enter in the values and boom :D

Comment: Yes but a script can not be used as a effect. But yeah i will write a script as soon as i have a computer.

Comment: @joojaa here's [a link](https://nofile.io/f/ga0dkDOBEQ4/RandomResize.js) for the RandomResize one, which probably just requires a few changes to make it move instead of resize.

Comment: Yeah but resize is a 1D variate while move is 2D much more possible distributions on 2D. Anyway random is relatively simple, unless you want cryptographical security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

Here is a implementation of uniform box scatter

```
scatter_box(activeDocument.selection, 100, 100);

function scatter_box(items, xoffset, yoffset){
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
       var oldpos = items[i].position;
       items[i].position= [oldpos[0]+Math.random()*xoffset-xoffset/2,
                           oldpos[1]+Math.random()*yoffset-yoffset/2];    
    }    
}
```

Here for uniform disc scatter.

```
scatter_disk(activeDocument.selection, 50);


function scatter_disk(items, rad){
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
       var oldpos = items[i].position;
       var r = Math.sqrt(Math.random()*rad*rad);
       var theta = Math.random()*2*Math.PI;
       items[i].position= [oldpos[0]+r*Math.sin(theta),
                           oldpos[1]+r*Math.cos(theta)];    
    }    
}
```

Obviously you could use other random distributions too.

---

### GUI version

```
#target illustrator

buildGUI();

function buildGUI(){
    var resource =
    "dialog { text:'jooScatter',\
        properties:{ closeButton:true, maximizeButton:false,\
            minimizeButton:false, resizeable:false },\
        orientation:'row', spacing:2, margins:5,\
        alignChildren:['left','fill'],\
        g: Group {\
                alignChildren:['left','fill'],\
                orientation:'column', spacing:20,margins:5,\
            p1: Panel {\
                text: 'Scatter Offsets:',\
                g1: Group {\
                    orientation:'column',\
                    x: Group {\
                        st: StaticText { text:'x width:'},\
                        f: EditText {text:'100', characters:20}\
                    },\
                    y: Group {st2 : StaticText{ text:'y width:'},\
                        f: EditText { text:'100' , characters:20 },\
                    },\
                },\
            },\
           g2: Group { alignment: 'right', orientation:'row',\
           apply: Button { text: 'Apply'},\
           cancel: Button { text:'Cancel'},\
       }\
       }\
    }"
    var win = new Window (resource);

    var cancel = function() {
         win.close(0);
    }
    var apply = function() {
         scatter_box(activeDocument.selection,
            eval(win.g.p1.g1.x.f.text),
            eval(win.g.p1.g1.y.f.text)
         );
         redraw();
    }

    win.g.g2.apply.onClick = apply;
    win.g.g2.cancel.onClick = cancel;

    win.show();



}

function scatter_box(items, xoffset, yoffset){
    for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
       var oldpos = items[i].position;
       items[i].position= [oldpos[0]+Math.random()*xoffset-xoffset/2,
                           oldpos[1]+Math.random()*yoffset-yoffset/2];    
    }    
}
```

*GIF of it in action [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAQ87.gif)*

Comment: These scripts *are* scatter scripts, but the value is already coded in the script, is there a way to make it give a pop-up for *me* to enter in a range at which it should scatter? (kinda like the other scripts I mentioned in my question)

Comment: @WELZ Sure that's just more work for no particular reward

Comment: Is there a way to make it where just moves the paths randomly between (-X and X) and (-Y and Y)? Where X and Y are entered in manually

Comment: the reward is that not every doc/group of paths is the same size, so I'd constantly have to go and edit the script to fit for that project.

Comment: @WELZ sure but you might aswell have extend script open and type     **scatter_box(activeDocument.selection, 100, 100)** Sicne the text is there just change it after thet and hit enter.

Comment: The gui layer is horrible so i would rather not do this. Its not like it kaes andy difference for your workflow if you jsut keep the script window open

Comment: It makes a difference in my workflow, because I don't usually leave scripts open. I appreciate what you've done so far! :-)

Comment: @WELZ added gui. I dont know why one would want a screen aligned box, when it could be rotated arbitrarily but your poison i guess.

Comment: Works perfectly for what I need, thanks a lot!