# How can I place randomly selected symbols onto a grid in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I have a bunch of square symbols that are all the same size. I would like to set random pre-designed symbols into a defined grid.

Square symbols:

[image]

Grid:

[image]

Symbols placed randomly within grid:

[image]

Is this at all possible?

Comment: Your question body asks for random position, while the title of the post requests randomly selected symbols, unrelated to position. I've answered the question in the body.

Comment: Clarification request: I think I understand you @user142377 as asking for a script, plugin or method allowing that you automagically position symbols, which are in aspect ratio square, into a defined grid. Further, you wish that the specific symbols placed are from a set you've created, and the "random" aspect is not positional, but rather a random selection out of that total selection set to be placed at each grid location. Is that correct?

Comment: @GerardFalla that is indeed correct, thank you for making sense of my end-of-day ramblings.

Answer (score 1):

Only answering here since this is a very old question and I know a solution which is **not my solution**.

---

There's a script posted at the **Adobe forum** to randomly replace symbols.
 This *seems* to me to be what is being requested here.

The Adobe Forums link is **[HERE](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/script-for-randomly-replacing-symbols/td-p/7165686)**.

The script, written by **[Qwertyfly](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/9816375)**, is as follows:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;


var sym = doc.symbols;


var sel = doc.selection;


for(var i = 0; i < sel.length; i++){


    var place = doc.symbolItems.add(sym[Math.floor(Math.random() * sym.length)]);


    place.height = sel.height;


    place.width = sel.width;


    place.top = sel.top;


    place.left = sel.left;


    sel.remove();


    place.selected = true;


}
```

The script will replace symbols with other, randomly selected, symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Using the search terms "illustrator script random position," I found a number of possible solutions. One of them is a [canned script](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/randomorder/22-1-0-253) from vectorboom.com in their free scripts section. It appears to allow to produce your objective.

[image: random placement image one]

Another result is an [answer within this SE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/111241/script-for-random-movement-scatter). It also appears to solve your goal, but is not as obvious to the eye.

[image: random placement image two]

There may be other solutions presented via the above-noted search terms.